# How to integrate $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} e^{-2\pi^2/x^2} dx$?

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, exponential-function

I am wondering how can i integrate this quantity above?

Here it is again,

$$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} e^{-2\pi^2/x^2}dx.$$

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You need brackets. Do you mean $\displaystyle\frac{e^{-2\pi}}{x^2}$? Or $\displaystyle\frac{e^{-2}\pi}{x^2}$ Or $\displaystyle\left(\frac{e^{-2\pi}}{x}\right)^2$? Or something else?

Comment: Is it $\int e^{-\frac{2\pi}{x^2}} dx$ ?

Comment: $\frac{(\int{e}dx)^{-2}\pi}{x^2}$ ? ;)

Comment: @EceBalkan What are your thoughts, how have you tried approaching this problem so far?

Comment: Sorry for ambiguity i am using this web site for the first time. I ve adjusted my question once again.

Comment: I am still thinking about whether it is has something to do with gaussian integral?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange ! In order to get some help, you are supposed to show your efforts, explain what you tried, tell where you are stuck ... So, try to show your work. Cheers :-)

Comment: In current form, the integral diverges because $e^{-2\pi^2/x^2} \to 1$ as $x \to \pm \infty$.

Comment: Or do you mean $$\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} e^{-2\pi \color{red}{\cdot} x^2} dx$$ ? In this case you can work with the gaussian integral.

Comment: so for gaussian integral the exponent of x must be positive? @calculus

Comment: No, the exponent i still negative-because of the negative sign. But $x^2$ has to be in the numerator of the exponent.

Comment: @EceBalkan Your are right. The exponent of x has to be positive.

Answer (score 1):

Since the function is even then
\begin{align}
 I = \int_{ - \infty }^\infty  {\exp \left( { - \frac{{2\pi ^2 }}{{x^2 }}} \right)dx}  = 2\int_0^\infty  {\exp \left( { - \frac{{2\pi ^2 }}{{x^2 }}} \right)dx}  
\end{align}
Setting
 \begin{align}
 x = \frac{{\sqrt 2 }}{{\sqrt u }}\pi ,\,\,\,\text{i.e.,}\,\,\,u = \frac{{2\pi ^2 }}{{x^2 }} \Rightarrow du =  - \frac{{4\pi ^2 }}{{x^3 }}dx \Rightarrow dx &=  - \frac{1}{{4\pi ^2 }}\left( {\frac{{\sqrt 8 }}{{\sqrt {u^3 } }}\pi ^3 } \right)du \\ 
 dx &=  - \frac{\pi }{{\sqrt 2 \sqrt {u^3 } }}du,
\end{align}
$x = 0,u \to \infty ;x = \infty ,u = 0$ 
\begin{align} 
 I = 2\int_\infty ^0 {\exp \left( { - u} \right)\frac{{ - \pi }}{{\sqrt 2 \sqrt {u^3 } }}du}  = \pi \sqrt 2 \int_0^\infty  {u^{-3/2} \exp \left( { - u} \right)du}   
\end{align}
But since $ \exp \left( { - u} \right) \ge 1-u$ then $ \int_0^\infty  {u^{-3/2} \exp \left( { - u} \right)du} \ge \int_0^\infty  {(1-u)u^{-3/2} du} $ and this is  diverge

Comment: this is false, the integral doesn't converge. the error is  in the second equality of your last line

Comment: Ok thanks, i correct my answer

Comment: By using $$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} \, t^{x-1} \, dt = \Gamma(x)$$ then the case of $x = -1/2$ leads to $$\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} \, t^{-3/2} \, dt = \Gamma\left(- \frac{1}{2}\right) = - 2 \sqrt{\pi}$$.

Comment: @Leucippus That isn't the analytic continuation of Gamma.  That is a divergent integral.